# REACT + VITE: [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./Card" from "src\components\Cards\Cards.jsx". Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, vite

tengo este error al compilar y aunque ya he probado todas las soluciones que encontré en stackoverflow y en la documentación (como modificar el archivo vite.config.js) e instalar las siguientes dependencias no logro resolverlo!

- npm i @vitejs/plugin-react
- npm i @vitejs/plugin-react-swc
- npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx
- npm install react-router-dom localforage match-sorter sort-by
- npm install -D eslint
- npm install react@latest react-dom@latest

este es el error en consola:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./App.css" from "src\App.jsx". Does the file exist?

[vite] Internal Server Error
Failed to resolve import "./Card" from "src\components\Cards\Cards.jsx". Does the file exist?
    at formatError (file:client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44062:46)
    at TransformContext.error (file:client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44058:19)
    at normalizeUrl (file:client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:41844:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async file:client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:41998:47
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at async TransformContext.transform (client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:41914:13)
    at async Object.transform (file:/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44352:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:55026:29)
```

y este mi archivo vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    hmr: {
      overlay: false,
    },
  },
})
```

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Es _Card_ o _Cards_?

Comment: este import está muy raro... `import "./Card" from "src\components\Cards\Cards.jsx"`